# No managed thread in dump created by orphaning IIS application pool of 64 bit ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, iis, 64-bit, windbg, deadlock

I need to find reason for Event ID 2262, Deadlock Detected of our ASP.NET application (64bit). It happens 1-3 times per day on our development server.

I created mini dump with full memory by orphaning the Application Pool as is described here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828222

I opened the dump with windbg and tried to find some managed thread: ~*e !clrstack

I received for all threads: Unable to walk the managed stack. The current thread is likely not a managed thread. You can run !threads to get a list of managed threads in the process

The same result I get when I take dump from command line (executing the same command as orphaning is set up for).

Should I take or view dump in different way?

For make windbg working I execute following commands:
.load c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscorwks.dll
.load c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\mscordacwks.dll
.load c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\sos.dll
.symfix "c:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows (x64)\cache"
.cordll -ve -u -l

And I have following dll in the dbg tools folder: mscordacwks_AMD64_X64_2.0.50727.3603.dll (taken from Framework64 directory).

I tried to explore all our logs and I didn't find any correlated data with deadlock failure time stamps. I reviewed and stressed the code committed into svn on the date of fist deadlock and several days before - no deadlock happened during the stress.

I bet on clr stack, thanks for any help,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

Did you load SOS, so that managed code can be debugged?  For .NET 4, the syntax is:

```
.loadby sos clr
```